# How to set up Kanna to parse xPath?

Tags: ios, swift, xpath

Here is what my view controller code looks like, and I am confused on why I am getting errors. Any help with this would be very appreciated! Thanks!

```
    import UIKit
    import Kanna


    let url = NSURL (string: "my website")
    let data = NSData (contentsOfURL: url!)
    let doc = HTML (html: data !, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let doc = Kanna.HTML(url: (NSURL(string: "the_site_url")!),     encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) {


// Search for nodes by XPath
for link in doc.xpath("//*[@id="hp-content"]/div[3]") {
    print(link.text)
    print(link["href"])
   }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 ] }


}
```

Comment: why your code is outside of the UIViewController ?

Comment: I just made a new test project so everything is default.

Comment: have you found a solution?